# Partitioning a table state

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, partitioning

So far I always used date ranges to partition my tables, however now I like to do it by state or a selected list of cities where all others that are not explicitly listed in an "other" partition, is this possible with SQL Server ?

Comment: Possibly if you provide surrogate values to represent the known set of values you want partitioned, and have those be 1-50 or 1-80 or whatever, and everything else is 51 or 81. I don't think you'd be able to do it with the state or city values themselves, because all of the unknowns would have to fall to the left or right of all of the knowns, and that seems pretty much impossible to me. Say you have Torino in one partition and Toronto in the next one, where do you put Torofino?

Comment: Since the value set of the state column is defined ahead I was hoping to tell it "AL","AK","AZ","OTHER" but fear was that it is really not possible with SQL Server. The idea is to provide different data buckets so I can speed up my imports, but then likely it is better to make different tables i guess. Thanks!

Comment: No, because partitioning on those values would be alphabetical. Just use surrogates, that's kind of what they're for.

Answer (score 1):

Create a secondary table with contiguous values for the known states (and maybe leave a little room for others you may want to segregate later):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.States
(
  StateID TINYINT PRIMARY KEY,
  Abbreviation CHAR(2)
  StateName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT dbo.States VALUES
(1,'AL','Alabama'),(2,'AK','Alaska'), ..., (51,'WY','Wyoming');

-- leave 52 - 68 available for other partitions

INSERT dbo.States VALUES
(69,'EH','Canada'),(70,'PR','Puerto Rico');
```

Now, in the partitioned table, you can partition against the StateID column, and just set up the partition scheme such that 69+ is its own partition.

You can't do this with state or city names because partitioning on those values can only be alphabetical. There's not really a clean way to say "put PA in its own partition, and RI in its own partition, but lump PR into another partition along with Guam."

Comment: [`CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187802.aspx) says: `boundary_value is a constant expression that can reference variables. This includes user-defined type variables, or functions and user-defined functions.` While that seems contradictory, using a function there would give the ability to abstract the surrogate values. I've never tried that before.

Comment: @Jon I'm not sure what you meant with the edit. If I have state values like `CA`, `AL`, `AK` etc. and I want to partition on that column, the partitioning has to be alphabetic, not numeric.

Comment: @Jon and yes, I've never tried that before using a function. Maybe it's possible, but I don't think it's intuitive and I'm not sure what type of performance implications exist.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. But, alphabetical as opposed to what? If the state is abstracted to a surrogate, that still doesn't accomplish the grouping very well since the groups have to have numerically sequential values.

Comment: @Jon sure it does, if the surrogates are stored in the partitioned table, there can be a partition for 1, a partition for 2, up to 68, and then 69+ is the last boundary.

Comment: I'm having a good day today. Upvoting and not commenting further. :)